# Поиск id используя API vkontakte и python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Есть список `url` и необходимо определить, какие из них принадлежат группе, а какие пользователям.

```
vk.com/id26514450
vk.com/im
vk.com/id20649754
vk.com/tania_sevostianova
vk.com/id335440760
vk.com/mvgtaobao
```

Как это можно сделать, используя `API vkontakte`?

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь методами [users.get()](http://vk.com/dev/users.get) и [groups.getById()](http://vk.com/dev/groups.getById).